# Is this the most straightforward way to handle this functionality?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, storyboard

I've created a button which changes its appearance when in different states, the way I do this (as a single example) when the button is being clicked down on:

```
 <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Green"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform). (TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.94"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform). (TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.94"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
```

Is there a way I could accomplish this using less code? I Just want the scale and colour to both instantly change to green when pressed, is there a way to do it without using keyframes?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just `DoubleAnimation` or `ColorAnimation', I suppose. But it is necessary to have 3 animations anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be written so:

```
<ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Green" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.94" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" />
<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.94" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" />
```

General animations are easier to understand and to use, and there is very few cases when frame animations can be used isnted of general animations.